# wamp on windows 10, Starting phpmyadmin throws an error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding()

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am an experienced developer, but:
I am new to Windows 10,
Having never used this tech at work, I am taking a class that is covering php, mysql, ajax, etc.

I installed wamp and in the process tried to follow the myriad instructions as to what to download and install before installing wamp.

Toy php/html files work as my instructor and online tutorials say they will work.

So to play with mysql, I was directed to start phpmyadmin via a browser, Chrome. It threw this error.

I tried to start phpmyadmin from the status bar gadget, same error.

Yes this question was asked before and answers given.
Many of the answers I could not understand, referring to tech I have not used.

The class uses wamp, so suggesting I use xamp etc., is not an option.

So how do I find out what is wrong? What am I to do?
One bit of advice on a similar thread said to use wampadmin. My response was: How?

So if you want to help, be detailed and specific. This is all new territory for me.

Comment: The installer for wamp directed me to download a number of libraries. I followed the links and downloaded them. 

Could it be that I missed a library, downloaded the wrong library, or downloaded the wrong version?

Answer (score 0):

1. Left click WAMP manager icon, which should be in the system tray (display bottom left corner)
2. From the context menu choose PHP -> php.ini
3. In php.ini find line ";extension=php_mbstring.dll"
4. Remove ';' from the line, it should be "extension=php_mbstring.dll"
5. Save php.ini
6. Restart Apache from WAMP manager menu

Comment: Thanks you for the response. Very clear for the newcomer.
Regretfully,
extension=php_mbstring.dll

was already live, no leading ;(semicolon) to delete.